# How do you set environment variables for Enide / Nodeclipse?

Tags: eclipse, node.js, nodeclipse, enide

Anyone know how to set environment variables for running and debugging Node.js applications in Eclipse + Nodeclipse aka Enide Studio? For example, in a .js file, an environment variable can be referenced as `process.env.PORT`, for the environment variable PORT. How can I specify this variable within Enide?

Comment: Correct names are Nodeclipse and Enide Studio, see http://www.nodeclipse.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to my question. First, go to the menu item `File > Properties`. Then select `Run/Debug Settings` from the options on the left of the dialog. Then select the `.js` file for which you want to set an environment variable during debugging/running programs in Enide Studio / Eclipse + Nodeclipse. Then select the `[Edit]` button. On the dialog that appears, select the `[Environment]` tab. Then select the `[New]` button and enter in your desired variable name and value. Repeat for multiple environment variables. Click `[Apply]`, then try running your program. Your environment values should be available as `process.env.YOUR_VARIABLE_NAME` in your Node.js source code.

Comment: Please be aware of issue #122 https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/issues/122